# Mysql String - Int comparsion

Tags: mysql

I m in a situation where i need to compare two tables against Projectnumber. Both tables has field ProjectNumber but one has datatype INT and other has VARCHAR(45). So when i try to run following query it result some un-matched records too

```
 Select prj.Projectnumber,ps.ProjectNumber as 'ProjectNumber2'
 from projectlistsearch ps 
 inner join project prj on ps.ProjectNumber= prj.ProjectNumber
```

This result some correct records but also result bad like this

```
ProjectNumber     ProjectNumber2
8                 08-809076
11                11-437881
11                11-505934
2007              2007-45750
2011              2011-0A76
```

I tried type casting as well but did not work.

How can i overcome this situation to get only completely matched record?

thanks

Comment: Is it MySQL or MS SQL Server? You tagged both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise to convert the `INT` to `VARCHAR` and compare those two, because for example converting a `VARCHAR` to `INT` when the text begins with decimal numbers, only the parseable prefix part will be converted to int:

Input:

```
'08-809076'
```

Parseable prefix:

```
08
```

Converted to `INT`

```
8
```

The other way round, the `VARCHAR` value `'8'` is compared against `'08-809076'` which will not match.

Answer (score 0):

Check casting functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

E.g.:

```
... WHERE CAST(prnumVarchar AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) = prnumInt;
```

Comment: i tried cast(ps.ProjectNumberas UNSIGNED INTEGER) , didn't work too

Comment: Well, i meant you should try: ... inner join project prj on CAST(ps.ProjectNumber AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) = prj.ProjectNumber